# Matlab: Find area enclosed by points (x,y)

Tags: matlab, polygon, area, points

I've got 8 points that create the outline of an eight-sided polygon in two-dimensional space. I need to find the area enclosed be these points, but how do I do that using matlab?

The eight points (x,y) are contained in the 8x2 matrix B.

```
B = [ 260 455;
    1187 467;
    1325 605;
    1342 1533;
    1207 1675
    251 1690;
    107 1547;
    116 593];
```

The polygon is created by drawing straight lines from the point which is row 1 to row 2, then row 2 to row 3 and so on...

Comment: first create a mask using roipoly and then find area using bwarea

Comment: @Parag - that could be fairly inefficient if the numbers are large. It will also be inaccurate in some cases, especially when a better answer - to use polyarea - is so trivial.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`polyarea`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html):

```
ar = polyarea(B(:, 1), B(:, 2));
```

Comment: There are many possible solutions to this question but I think this is the most efficient, as it is the built in function that does _exactly_ what OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **trapezoid**:

```
Area = trapz(B(:,1),B(:,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

For calculating area and even volume you can use [convhull](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html).