# Finding the area of a non-uniform shape

Tags: matlab, area

I was wondering if anyone here has experience with finding the area of a non-uniform shape in MATLAB. I would like to know which method will give me the best approximation.

Comment: Your question is vague and will likely be closed; please provide more details such as the type of image, some code you have tried so far maybe. In the meantime you might want to look into bwarea open or especially regionprops with the 'Area' option.

Comment: Fair point Benoit, I've assumed that @BranH has a list of points that they wish to calculate the area of

If so my answer applies, but also a possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579602/matlab-find-area-enclosed-by-points-x-y

Comment: Hi guys,Well I have created a shape by plotting two functions against eachother and would like to find the area. I can upload my functions? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The built-in method [polyarea](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html) is reasonably popular. It takes a list of X and Y points for a polygon and calculates the area.

e.g.

```
points = [ 0 0; 0 10; 10 10; 0 10; 0 0 ];
area = polyarea(points(:,1), points(:,2))
```

Note that I've close the polygon before passing it to polyarea