# How to find area enclosed by points in octave using Quadrature or any other method

Tags: octave, area, points

I have two sets of coordinates (both positive and negative values, not necessarily in increasing order, and in many cases there are **different values of y for the same value of x**) which I can load into two row vectors of equal size.

I want to calculate the area enclosed by the curve.
How to do it with octave?

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579966/3128341) but it does not work because it seems that the area printed (204.64) is too high (see picture).

I tried the code:

```sh
function showdata(fName)
    M = dlmread(fName);
    H = M(2:end, 1); % starting row number is 2
    B = M(2:end, 2);
    aux = figure();

    plot(H, B,'linewidth',2);
    xlabel ("Auxilary field H (A/m)"); 
    ylabel ("Magnetic Field B (Tesla)");
    area = polyarea(H,B)

    axis([min(H), max(H), min(B), max(B)]);
    grid on;
    grid minor on;
    title (area,"fontsize",20);
```

Then I am calling `showdata('data.txt')` in Octave.
Picture of Data points:
[image]

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqidiburde8jg32/data.txt?dl=0) is the data file I am using.

Comment: Could you please provide the file with the shown data, so that one can reproduce your results?

Comment: @HansHirse Done

Comment: I bet the data goes through many cycles, not just one. You thus don’t have a (simple, non-intersecting) polygon. The value calculated is `N * area`, with `N` the number of cycles recorded.

Comment: would using getframe and imfill be a feasible solution? ;-)

Comment: @Andy It turned out that there were multiple cycles, as predicted by Cris Lingo, and I manually selected only one cycle. If you have any other solution, you can of course provide an answer. I don't know how to use getframe and infill.

Comment: if the data go through many cyclese, I might try to find the convex hull fo the data and use surveyor's formula to get the are of the convex hull. Go wiki surveyor's formula and Convex hull might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for computing convex hull called "[convhull](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Convex-Hull.html)" in Octave. It returns the indices of the points formming convex hull data.

```
M = dlmread("data.txt"); #I removed the header in data.txt 
x = M(:,1);
y = M(:,2);
k = convhull(x,y);
plot (x(k), y(k), "r-", x, y, "b+");
n = rows(k);
x_prime = vertcat(x(k(n)), x(k(1:n-1)));
y_prime = vertcat(y(k(n)), y(k(1:n-1)));
A = .5*abs(x_prime'*y(k)-y_prime'*x(k)); #80.248
polyarea(x(k), y(k)) == A and true
```

[image]
Maybe convex hull is not good estimate of area because the top left and the down-right lines are a little far away from the points. There are other ways to form a polygon from data
, one of which could be alpha shape. However, alpha shape are more complicated and there is no corresponding pre-built function in Octave.

Update:
Each x corresponds to at least one y cordinate. I marked the highest point and lowest point laying on the same x and estimate the area again.
There is the code:

```
[uni, ~] = sort(unique(x));
n = rows(uni);
outline = [];
for i = 1:n
  y_list = y(x==uni(i));
  [y_max, ~] = max(y_list);
  outline(i, :)= [uni(i), y_max];
  [y_min, ~] = min(y_list);
  outline(2*n-i+1,:)= [uni(i), y_min];
endfor
figure;
plot (x(k), y(k), "r-", x, y, "b+", outline(:,1), outline(:,2), "g-", "linewidth", 3);
polyarea(outline(:,1), outline(:,2)) #74.856
```

[image]
By the way, if the arguments of function polyarea do not form a close curve function polyarea would return wrong area.
Four point on a unit square:
[(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)], [(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)]

`polyarea([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1])!==polyarea([0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1])`.